# How to move all my data on one firefox to another

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

All,
I have one firefox installation at work that has specific add-ons, each add-on having it's own preferences and history/data.

Is there a tool/steps to move the entire data to my personal PC, so that I do not have to set-up everything all over again?

My workstation is Windows XP SP3
and
my personal PC is Windows 7, professional, 64bit.

Thanks

Comment: This is not programming related, is it? Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: @Pekka I am sorry. How can I move it to superuser.com? Sorry for inconvenience guys.

Comment: No problem. I flagged for migration, a mod will probably do it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your Explorer and type in: %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\

If you didn't create another profile there should be one folder with ".default" at the end of it's name. Just copy this folder to the same directory on your desktop pc.

Have fun :)